# is RSA private key less than public?

Tags: openssl, rsa

when i generate RSA key pairs by OpenSSL, it seems like private key (private exponent) is always less than public key (modulus). Is it by RSA design?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about RSA keys and doesn't contain a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a requirement, but there is no reason for it to be larger than the modulus:

The private exponent `d` is calculated from the public exponent `e` and modulus `n` to satisfy:

```
ed ≡ 1 mod φ(n)
```

Now, if we assume that `d > φ(n)`, then we can define `d' = d mod φ(n)`, and not only is `d' < φ(n)`, but the above relation still holds, i.e.:

```
ed' ≡ 1 mod φ(n)
```

Thus `d'` is also a valid private exponent, and since `φ(n) < n`, `d'` must also be less than `n`.

Since a larger private exponent requires more storage, and (at least in the naïve implementation) makes decryption slower, the smallest possible private exponent is the most suitable.

Answer (score -2):

No it is not important to the cryption itself. (Check wikipedia how rsa works). Maybe its implemented this way but its no must for the algo

Comment: wiki says that private exponent d "is the multiplicative inverse of e (modulo φ(n))". Does it say anything to non-math-professor? - No. Can you prove mathematically that formula d⋅e ≡ 1 (mod φ(n)) does not mean what i asked about?

Comment: It should mean something, we did it in 10th class :o i dont understand your actual problem